# Drupal.org API for fetching a specific user’s all contributions

Tags: community-official-site

I’m looking for an API from drupal.org which will give a JSON of the contributions(credit, commit) for a specific username. I got this https://www.drupal.org/api-d7/user.json?name=[username] but this doesn't have the contributions listed here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this should be posted on drupal.org.